# Search Custom Template Directory first when using Smarty {include}

Tags: civievent, message-templates, smarty, system-workflow-messages

I'm sure this is easy but the answer has escaped me. On a drupal install CiviCRM is installed at:
`/webtree/mysite/htdocs/sites/www.mysite/modules/civicrm`

I have a Custom Template File directory set to 
`/webtree/mysite/htdocs/sites/www.mysite/files/civicrm/templates`

I'd like to store a custom template file "someText.tpl" in the Custom Template File directory that, depending on some logic, may get included in the Online Event Registration system workflow message using the command:

`{include file="someText.tpl"}`

If I place the file at: 
`/webtree/mysite/htdocs/sites/www.mysite/modules/civicrm/templates/someText.tpl`
it is read just fine, but I haven't been able to find a way to place it at 
`/webtree/mysite/htdocs/sites/www.mysite/files/civicrm/templates`

I've tried assorted dot notation, full paths, etc. but can't seem to read and include a template that isn't in the module/civicrm/templates path. I'd rather not store my custom files there because it creates extra steps during upgrades.  Any suggestions?

Comment: In your second last paragraph, both paths are the same. Maybe the first should point to the module template path.

Comment: If you look close they're a little different, the first is INSIDE the default install location for CiviCRM (sites/mysite/MODULES/civicrm.. while the second is outside that location (sites/mysite/FILES/...UPDATE You're right, I typed it wrong. edited now.

Comment: Are your Directories and Resource URLs correctly set?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information about overriding templates and the Custom Template Directory in the developer guide [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/customizing/)... along with the recommendation that you don't do that but use extensions instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just elaborate Aidan's answer:

At Administration Console, Directories, at field: Custom Template Directory, fill in say:
`[civicrm.files]/custom_templates/`

It refers to directory `<DocRoot>/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_templates`
Go there and make any necessary directory structure corresponding to your include statement. If it is {include file="CRM/Report/Form.tpl"}, then mkdir -p CRM/Report and put Form.tpl there. It would be used if there is a hit.

In case you feel the tpl file you put there is not used, please try this: Administer, System Settings, Cleanup Caches and Update Paths, just click Cleanup Caches. Then go to Dashboard and click Refresh Dashboard Data. Then visit your custom component and see the new changes.